# successRedirect with passport-facebook not working

Tags: oauth-2.0, passport.js, passport-facebook

I am trying to use passport-facebook for logging in with my app. I am having some trouble redirecting when the user actually logs in. Basically the issue is that after going to /auth/facebook and redirecting to facebook login (and entering credentials, then hitting login button) the page will load forever, and not redirect. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my app.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import session from 'express-session';
import passport from 'passport';
import FacebookStrategy from 'passport-facebook'; 
const app = express();



var fbOpts = {
    clientID: ****,
    clientSecret: ****,
    callbackURL: '/auth/facebook/callback',
    profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'email']
}

var fbCallback = (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
    console.log(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb);
    //save to database
}


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({
    secret:'foobar',
    resave:true,
    saveUnitialized:true
}))

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(fbOpts,fbCallback))

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.send("<a href='/auth/facebook'>Login with Facebook</a>")
});

app.get("/auth/facebook",passport.authenticate('facebook'));


app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/'
    })
);


app.get("/profile",(req,res)=>res.send("profile page"))


app.listen(3000);
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing or doing wrong with redirecting back to my website ?

Also, I can tell the login is properly working because if I look in my terminal's console I can see my user information for facebook, such as profile picture, name, id, etc.

Comment: What is your callback URL on the Facebook App?

Answer (score 1):

you've probably fixed this by now. But just for anybody else out there trying to get around this. There are many reference points that you ought to look out for. I tried to change the redirect stuff on https://developers.facebook.com/apps for ages but nothing was working. Kept getting the message URL Blocked. Whitelist etc etc.

The problem was actually solved because in my ids file where i stored my id's I had set the callbackURL: 'http://**127.0.0.1**:3000/auth/facebook/callback' instead of callbackURL: **localhost**:3000.

Silly mistake, but just thought i would share to let you know to keep checking all the possible reference points.